# C++ - Print Out Objects From Set

Tags: c++

If I have a C++ set and iterator:

```
set<Person> personList;
set<Person>::const_iterator location;
```

How can I print out the contents of the set? They are all person objects, and I have overloaded operator<< for Person.

The line that errors is in a basic for loop:

```
cout << location
```

Netbeans gives:

> proj.cpp:78: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << location’

It looks like it wants an overload for the iterator's operator<<.

Basically, I am taking objects that used to be stored in an array format, but are now in a set. What is the equivalent to `cout << array[i]` for sets?

Answer (score 24):

In C++11, why use a for loop when you can use a foreach loop?

```
#include <iostream> //for std::cout

void foo()
{
    for (Person const& person : personList)
    {
        std::cout << person << ' ';
    }
}
```

In C++98/03, why use a `for` loop when you can use an algorithm instead?

```
#include <iterator> //for std::ostream_iterator
#include <algorithm> //for std::copy
#include <iostream> //for std::cout

void foo()
{
    std::copy(
        personList.begin(),
        personList.end(),
        std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, " ")
        );
}
```

Note that this works with any pair of iterators, not only those from `std::set<t>`. `std::copy` will use your user-defined `operator<<` to print out every item inside the `set` using this single statement.

Answer (score 7):

You need to dereference the iterator:

```
 std::cout << *location;
```

The convention of using the indirection or dereferencing operator to get the referenced value for an iterator was chosen in analogy to pointers:

```
 person* p = &somePerson;
 std::cout << *p;
```

Comment: Oh, I see. This is also why the arrow operator allows me to access the object's fields. Thanks!

Comment: Cant I print a set without using an iterator, like:
`for(int i=0; i<=s.size(); ++i)
    cout<<s[i]<<" ";` like we do in case of vectors. I did this and it said no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘s[i]’

Comment: @Sunny: No, `std::set` doesn't provide that. FWIW, it looks nearly the same with iterators: `for(SetType::const_iterator it=s.begin();it!=s.end();++it) cout<<*it;`. If you need more details you should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @GeorgFritzsche Yeah I came to know that Set is an associative container so we can't do what I mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

it is a set::iterator

```
   for(it = output_set.begin(); it != output_set.end(); it++)
    {
        outstream_1 << *it << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

begin() is a built-in function in C++ STL function which used to return an iterator pointing to the first element of the set container.

end() is a built-in function in C++ STL which is used to get an iterator to past the last element. The past-the-end element is the theoretical element that would follow the last element in the vector. It does not point to any element, and thus shall not be dereferenced.

Also, the objects in Set are distinct values stored in ascending or descending order.

example 1:

```
set<char> myset{'a', 'c', 'g', 'z'}; 
for (auto it=myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it)     
cout << ' ' << *it;
```

output :  a c g z

example 2:

```
set<string> myset{"This", "is", "confused"}; 
for (auto it=myset.begin(); it != myset.end(); ++it) 
cout << ' ' << *it;
```

output :  This confused is

Answer (score 0):

```
// Online C++ compiler to run C++ program online
#include <iostream>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

struct Car
{
    int m;
    int p;
    void set(int a,int b){
        m =a,p = b;
    }
};
struct Car cT[50];
int cI=0;

bool operator < (const Car& c1,const Car& c2){
    return c1.p < c2.p;
}
ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const Car& a)
    {
        o << "Car Model: " << a.m << " price: " << a.p << endl;
        return o;
    }

void insertS(set<Car>& c){
    for(int i=0;i<cI;i++){
        c.insert(cT[i]);
    }
}

void printS(set<Car> c){
    set<Car> :: iterator i;
    for( i=c.begin();i!=c.end();i++){
        cout << *i<<endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    set<Car> mCs;
    cT[cI++].set(4,5);
    cT[cI++].set(34,4);
    cT[cI++].set(43,6);
    cT[cI++].set(41,15);
    insertS(mCs);
    printS(mCs);

    return 0;
}
```

Output will be:::

```
Car Model: 34 price: 4

Car Model: 4 price: 5

Car Model: 43 price: 6

Car Model: 41 price: 15
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).